# How to embed in view (i.e. group UI elements) programmatically

Tags: xcode

In X-Code, I can do "Editor -> Embed In -> View/Scrollview" to group UI widgets together. How is that done programmatically?

Is it same as doing addSubView to a parent view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the **same**.
 For example to add a `UILabel` to a `UIScrollView`, simply type `myScrollView.addSubview(myLabel)` and your label is added to the `ScrollView`.

Hope that helps :)